# Is a P2WPKH address synonymous with a Bech32 address?

Tags: address, segregated-witness, terminology, bech32-address, p2wpkh

[BIP142](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0142.mediawiki#example) when encoding a segwit P2WPKH address is using a base58 address format (address `p2xtZoXeX5X8BP8JfFhQK2nD3emtjch7UeFm` in the example).

I understand that BIP142 predates [BIP173](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki) but are P2WPKH and Bech32 synonyms now? Is there such a thing as Base58 P2WPKH address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> are P2WPKH and Bech32 synonyms now?

No. Bech32 is also used for P2WSH addresses. Native segwit and Bech32 are synonyms.

> Is there such a thing as Base58 P2WPKH address?

No.

Comment: Not quite; Bech32 is just the encoding scheme, which is more general than Bitcoin's use of it for P2WSH/P2WPKH addresses.

Answer (score 1):

*P2WPKH* and *bech32* are not quite synonymous.

**Native segwit** describes a type of output schema in which the `scriptPubKey` (the "locking script") is composed of a witness version and a witness program. P2WPKH is a native segwit v0 output type.

**Bech32** refers to an encoding scheme and an address format to represent a recipient's `scriptPubKey` in out-of-band communication.

We use "bech32 addresses" to instruct spenders to create "P2WPKH outputs":

- Pay to Witness Public Key Hash (P2WPKH) and Pay to Witness Script Hash (P2WSH) are native segwit v0 outputs that get represented using **bech32** addresses.
- Pay to Public Key Hash (P2PKH) and Pay to Script Hash (P2SH) use **base58** addresses.
- Pay to Taproot (P2TR) and future native segwit output types will use **bech32m** addresses.